# Target array position to add icon image in google map marker function with icon array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-maps

This is how google recommends adding many markers on the map with unique icons for each item:

```
 var icons = {
          parking: {
            icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
          }
        };
var features = [
          {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91721, 151.22630),
            type: 'info'
          }
];
        for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: features[i].position,
            icon: icons[features[i].type].icon,
            map: map
          });
        };
      }
```

For the sake of re-doing my code. I am trying to implement it in my own way with my current PHP array. It looks like:
`["TITLE", "LAT", "LNG", "Z-INDEX", "CATEGORY"]`
When targeting the positions in my array to set the data to create the marker it looks like the following:

```
function setMarkers(markers) {
   deleteMarkers(); 
var iconBase =
            'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/';
var icons = {
         Parking: {
            icon: iconBase + 'parking_lot_maps.png'
          }
        };
    if (markers){
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var w = markers[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: parseFloat(w[1]), lng: parseFloat(w[2])},
      map: map,
      icon: icons[w[4]].icon,
      title: w[0],
      zIndex: parseFloat(w[3])
    });
  }   
 }
}
```

Everything works perfectly until I get to the `ICON:` line, I cannot seem to target the Category part in the array and have it find the `icon:` inside the icons var. I either get an error saying "cannot read property 4 of undefined" or it says that the function is not defined. Any ideas of what I can do without re-coding it? thanks!!

Comment: also add the markers array

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: you are iterating  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++); show us the content of markers or sample market object

Comment: isnt that what the array i posted above is? `["TITLE", "LAT", "LNG", "Z-INDEX", "CATEGORY"]`

Comment: so you basically have array of arrays right?

Comment: yes, on my PHP side it looks like: `$markers[]=array($title,$latitude,$longitude,'3',$category);`

Comment: I have tested it using example it works perfectly.make sure icons object has a property name same as w[4] value ..Check the uppercase and lower case

Comment: i dont know why, i keep getting error "Cannot read property 'icon' of undefined"

Comment: how many markers do you have? and how are you setting the initial array of markers

Comment: I was able to correct it, one of the caregories being loaded in did not have an image that corresponded with it. That was the issue. But your confirmation that it worked helped me develop the solution. thank you for your time! I will mark correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work perfectly. Check for mismatch in properties of icons object and market object's category value

```js
 var icons = {
         Parking: {
            icon: 'parking_lot_maps.png'
          }
        };
let w=["TITLE", "LAT", "LNG", "Z-INDEX", "Parking"];
console.log(w[4]);
console.log(icons[w[4]]);
console.log(icons[w[4]].icon)
```